# Why when calling and using a specific year in a dataset does python return it as non-callable?

Tags: python, pandas, file

So I am creating a code to find the time-varying Value-at-Risk using yearly windows from a file I have imported and shown  below.
[image]

When creating the code to find the yearly daily returns in Year 1964 for example (from 1/2/1964 to 12/31/1964) as a baseline distribution, and calculate the value from a 2.5% return. However when I run this code I get the error  ( 'DataFrame' object is not callable). Is there way to workaround this or fix it?

```
    year1=data(YEAR[0])
    data1_location = (year1)*2.5/100    # 2.5% is the rate for this formula
    extreme = [int(data1_location)]        # sorts the data location I created
    print("The extreme value that is asbsociated with the lower 2.5% is"(data1_location))
```

Comment: The expression `data(YEAR[0])` is attempting to call `data` as if it were a function.  It's not, so you get an error telling you that it's not callable.  You probably meant `data[YEAR[0]]`.  Square brackets (`[]`) are for *subscripting* a subscriptable object (like a dataframe, a list, a dict, etc), parens (`()`) are for *calling* a callable object (like a function or a type).

Comment: yes I see but when I run the code with the square brackets I get code 1964 as an error.

Comment: The error states this more specifically: "KeyError: 1964

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to create a subset of your original DataFrame for a given year.

However, `YEAR[0]` will be equal to `1964`, which you cannot use directly for indexing your DataFrame.

For getting all items for the year 1964, use

```
year1 = data[data['yyyy'] == '1964']
```

Next thing is that `year1` is again a data frame which you cannot use in an arithmetic operation. Probably you want something like this:

```
year1['value'] = year1['RET_SP500']*2.5/100
```

or similar (it's not quite clear to me from your question what you need to caluclate). This creates a new column with the result of the formula.
Then you can operate on this column, for example create a list of entries or find the maximum or minimum value.

Comment: I see and thank you but when I run the code to print the value given it returns this "The extreme value that is asssociated with the lower 2.5% is Series([], Name: value, dtype: float64)"  and the number calculated is not returned